# Clojure: Converting Clojure File to YAML

Tags: clojure, yaml

How would you convert a clojure source file to YAML? I have used the [clj-yaml](https://github.com/lancepantz/clj-yaml) library to do it in the interactive REPL, but I'd like to automate this, so I can pass in an input file and specify an output, ie:

```
clj2yaml input.clj > output.yml
```

Comment: check out the `lein-exec` plugin; its perfect for this https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it you need help to read and write the files?! See [slurp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp) and [spit](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/spit). For a real example of reading a YAML config file and parsing it with clj-yaml, see [pswincom.gateway.config](https://github.com/tormaroe/pswincom-clj/blob/5c947b2048835bc51613a505b0cbfd2fbe18badf/src/pswincom/gateway/config.clj).

And here's an implementation of a simple clojure tool to do the convertion:

```
(ns sample
    (:require [clj-yaml.core :as yaml]))

(->> (slurp (nth *command-line-args* 0))
     read-string ; converts the file content to a clojure datastructure
     yaml/generate-string
     (spit (nth *command-line-args* 1)))
```

(On Windows) I can create a batch file called clj2yaml.bat to make it easy to use. It assumes the needed jar-files are located in the current directory. I'm just a novice when it comes to this kind of execution, so a better script is quite likely possible, but here it is:

```
java.exe -cp .\clojure-1.2.0.jar;.\clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar;.\clj-yaml-0.3.0-20101010.033133-1.jar;.\snakeyaml-1.5.jar clojure.main sample.clj %*
```

I can now execute `clj2yaml foo.clj foo.yaml` to create the yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to code a clojure converter, you now just need to package it as a standalone application, and possibly create a sh script that just invokes your class.

As an alternative, here's a [neat way to do it](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Tutorials_and_Tips#Shebang_Scripting_in_Clojure), if you're on a *nix environment:

```
#^:shebang '[
exec java -cp "$HOME/src/clj/clojure/clojure.jar" clojure.lang.Script "$0" -- "$@"
]
(your code here)
```

Comment: I should add that I can convert it in the interactive REPL when essentially pasting my string in. my lack of clojure knowledge is limiting in terms of how I actually read in, convert, and write out the converted data with clojure. thank you for you reply